# Writing for loop expression in one line in python but Result should not be a list

Tags: python, lambda

I want some ids in a loop which is easy to get but the problem is I want to apply loop in one line. I have tried it using a list comprehension but I don't want the result as a list type.

I have ids in this object:

```
location(282, 285, 284, 283)
```

I can get them by simply applying loop:

```
for i in location:
    print(i.id)
```

It will give me this result:

```
282
285
284
283
```

I got a result in this type and this is what I really want.

```
[x for x in location]
```

This gives me result in a list

```
[282,285,284,283]
```

But I don't want this.

I want a result in this form but the loop should be written in one line in python.

```
282
285
284
283
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the ids when you get them? What's wrong with: `for i in location: print(i.id)` ? (all on one line)

Comment: x =[print(x, end=' ')for x in location]. Though I'm completely unsure why you would wish for something like that.

Comment: @BornTbeWasted This seems to have no functional use.  My guess is the OP is trying to make the code more "pythonic", but is mutilating it instead.

Comment: @tnknepp Agreed, that is why I just wanted to comment. I don't really get the "one-liner" trend to be honest. ^^

Comment: Actually i am asking this for a reason i have to stored the this inside a python dictionary for example {'key':'loop that gets the value'}.

Comment: Well your `loop that gets the value` looks like the `list` that you don't want. Or is is a space separated string of numbers?

Comment: @uba This would have been VERY helpful to know.  Next time, put that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To enter items into a `dict`, you may want somthing like this:

```
d = {}   # empty dict

loc = location(282, 285, 284, 283)

values = ' '.join([str(i.id) for i in loc])

key = 'loc1'

d[key] = values
```

Or you can still have your `list` that you don't want:

```
value = [i for i in loc]
d[key] = values
```

Comment: Hello i want to thanks everyone for their feedback . I think i have been able to get my required answer so i though i must share it . I think what i need was to use filter and lambda function . Something like `filter(lamda x : x.example == "test").id` using filter is the way we could get looping results in one line .

Comment: You need to mention these sorts of things in your question. ie there is an `example` attribute which has to equal something like `"test"`.